# How to pass a variable from python to an HTML tag

Tags: python, pandas

I'm kind of new to python programming. I want to send a mail to a number of people with different values for each mail. So, i created a csv file for my list and imported it into python. Also created an HTML tag and tried to pass the variables from the list. But it won't give the variable when the email is being sent. What i'm i doing wrong? Below is the copy of my code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv, smtplib, ssl


file = pd.read_csv('contacts.csv')
contacts = pd.DataFrame(file)


for i in range(len(contacts)):
    name,email,amount,rate=contacts.iloc[i]
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
   
    body=body =open('template 2.txt').read()
   
 
    message=body.format(name.split()[0],amount,rate) 
       
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, "html"))
    text=message.as_string()
   
   message.as_string().format(name=row[0],amount=row[2],rate=row[3]))
        print('Sent To: ',name)   
print('Done')
print(message)
```

I get the error below when i run the full code.

```
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2bb1b4499d0d> in <module>
     30     message["To"] = email
     31     message["From"] = myemail
---> 32     message=body.format(name.split()[0],amount,rate)
     33     #message=body.format(name.split()[0],amount,rate) #of {} Thank You for chosing us.".format(name.split()[0],amount,rate)
     34                # message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

KeyError: 'text-decoration'
```

I tried passing the variables into this part of the html code like shown below

```
                                  <td>Dear {name},<br><br>You Payout has been processed. Below is the details of the payout.<br><br></td> 
                            
                                  <td>Amount Processed<br>{amount}</td> 
                               
                                  <td>Rate Used for Processing<br>{rate}</td>
```

I'll appreciate any help i can get as i have spent a lot of time on this.

Comment: is it a must for you to use `smtplib`, can you use `win32com.client` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.format` with template with named places, you should use keyword arguments, for example:

```
template_1 = "{x} plus {y} is {z}"
message = template_1.format(x=10, y=2, z=12)
print(message)
```

output:

```
10 plus 2 is 12
```

So you need to replace

```
message=body.format(name.split()[0],amount,rate)
```

using

```
message=body.format(name=name.split()[0], amount=amount, rate=rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of doing this is using named parameters in "moustache" notation and apply them using the `.format` syntax.

So you construct some template, or series of template strings like:

```
main_html_template = """ <html> {content} </html"""

content_html_template = """ <body> <p> Dear {person}, \n {message} </p> <p> Kind regards, \n {sender} </p> </body> """
```

Then do some variable assignments - here I'm just assigning flat strings, but you could assign these using more interesting construction functions.

```
person = "Aderemi"
message = "welcome to python!"
sender = "Tom"
```

Then join them together like so:

```
content = content_html_template.format(person=person, message=message, sender=sender)
html = main_html_template .format(content=content)
```

This is (kind of) close to how some [templating engines](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) used in [common web-apps](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/) expose similar templating functionality, so can be good to try out before one day moving to using one of those.

Another trick I kind of like is how you can place all your variables into a dictionary, and then use unpacking asterisks to convert the dictionary into your format mapping.

e.g. Rather than:

```
content = content_html_template.format(person=person, message=message, sender=sender)
```

If you first create a parameter dictionary like this:

```
content_parms = { "person" : "Aderemi", 
                  "message" : "welcome to python!"
                  "sender" : "Tom"
```

Then you can use that to drive your content formatting using ** unpacking like this:

```
content = content_html_template.format(**content_parms)
```

Which doesn't give you additional functionality, but might be a convenient way of structuring your program.

And the final output of all this should be:

```
' <html>  <body> <p> Dear Aderemi, \n welcome to python! </p> <p> Kind regards, \n Tom </p> </body>  </html'
```